# Karatsuba multiplier using byte[]

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to implement the Karatsuba algorithm that multiplies two byte arrays, which always have the same length, without using `BigInteger` class.

Here is my code. Can you help find the bug?:

```
static public byte[] Karatsuba(byte[] X, byte[] Y, int N)
{
    if (N == 1)
    {
        int result = X[0] * Y[0];
        byte[] resArray = new byte[2] { (byte)(result % 10), (byte)(result / 10) };
        return resArray;
    }

    int half = N / 2;
    byte[] xLow, xHigh, yLow, yHigh;
    Split(X, half, out xLow, out xHigh);
    Split(Y, half, out yLow, out yHigh);

    byte[] z0 = Karatsuba(xLow, yLow, half);
    byte[] z2 = Karatsuba(xHigh, yHigh, half);
    byte[] z1;

    z1 = Karatsuba(Add(xLow, xHigh, half), Add(yLow, yHigh, half), half);
        
    z1 = Subtract(Subtract(z1, z0, half), z2, half);

    byte[] resultArray = new byte[2 * N];
    Array.Copy(z0, 0, resultArray, 0, z0.Length);
    Array.Copy(z1, 0, resultArray, half, z1.Length);
    Array.Copy(z2, 0, resultArray, 2 * half, z2.Length);

    return resultArray;
}

private static void Split(byte[] x, int half, out byte[] low, out byte[] high)
{
    low = new byte[half];
    high = new byte[half];
    Array.Copy(x, 0, low, 0, half);
    Array.Copy(x, half, high, 0, half);
}

private static byte[] Add(byte[] a, byte[] b, int length)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[length];
    byte carry = 0;

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        byte sum = (byte)(a[i] + b[i] + carry);
        result[i] = (byte)(sum % 10);
        carry = (byte)(sum / 10);
    }

    return result;
}

private static byte[] Subtract(byte[] a, byte[] b, int length)
{
    int n = length;
    byte[] result = new byte[n];
    int carry = 0;

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int sub = a[i] - b[i]-carry;
        if (sub < 0)
        {
            sub += 10;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0;
        }

        result[i] = (byte)sub;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I tried these test cases:

- N = 4
- X = 2185
- Y = 2185
- output = 04416205
- expect = 04774225
  and some testcases passed :
- N = 2
- X = 11
- Y = 22
- output = 0242
- expect = 0242
  i notice that the first number on the right is always as expected

Comment: How do you call your function with the first test case?

Comment: i create two byte arrays X={5,8,1,2} ,  Y={5,8,1,2} and pass it into function parameters .

Comment: In case it isn't clear from the question, the expected results are just traditional multiplication.  2185 * 2185 = 4774225 and 11 * 22 = 242.  Karatsuba is basically _long multiplication_ and numbers are stored as an array of digits. Each digit is base 10 in this example, and is stored in a byte, which is ample space for storing digits from 0-9.

Comment: I already tried with long numbers and it still gives wrong values i noticed that it give right values for only specific inputs . So i don't understand where is the bug in my code

Comment: Your `Add` function ignores the final carry which may be 1. This has cascading effects on the rest of your calculations.

Comment: How can i solve it ?

Comment: You'll need to rewrite the whole logic to work with variable lengths taking into account that adding of 2 values may result in a number that has one more byte. Same with adding up `z0`, `z1`, and `z2`. Those numbers -- when shifted -- may have overlapping digits... so you cannot just copy -- but must add.

Comment: i still cant solve the bug

Comment: Please don't alter the question like you did. It makes the answer(s) refer to code that is no longer there. You also removed the test cases that failed, which are an integral part of your question; and added stuff from the answer (the suggestion to use List, and the problem with the Add function). I rolled back those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not just one bug. There are several issues:

- The `Add` function discards the final carry, so that you may lose one digit in the result. Because you cannot assume that the sum of two numbers has the same number of digits as the operands, even correcting this will have a cascading effect on the rest of your algorithm -- which no longer assume that all operands have the same number of digits.
- The `Add` and `Subtract` functions deal with the bytes as if they are stored from most significant to least significant, but the rest of your code deals with the bytes as ordered from least significant to most significant.
- `z0`, `z1` and `z2` are concatenated into one number assuming they don't have non-zero digits at the same final position, but this cannot be assumed. After `z1` and `z2` have been "shifted", they must be properly added to `z0` to get the final result

This all means this code has to be revamped considerably, so that:

- It supports operands of different sizes (for addition, subtraction, multiplication, split,...)
- It can remove padded zeroes that are not significant for the number represented by the bytes.
- It uses the `Length` property of arrays so that it is no longer necessary to pass a length argument to functions like `Karatsuba` or `Add`.

Here is the code that takes on board these comments for the functions you have provided (adding a couple more functions to perform common tasks):

```
static public byte[] Karatsuba(byte[] X, byte[] Y)
{
    int N = Math.Max(X.Length, Y.Length);
    if (X.Length == 1) return Mul(Y, X[0]);
    if (Y.Length == 1) return Mul(X, Y[0]);

    int half = N / 2;
    byte[] xLow, xHigh, yLow, yHigh;
    Split(X, half, out xLow, out xHigh);
    Split(Y, half, out yLow, out yHigh);

    byte[] z0 = Karatsuba(xLow, yLow);
    byte[] z2 = Karatsuba(xHigh, yHigh);
    byte[] z1 = Karatsuba(Add(xLow, xHigh), Add(yLow, yHigh));
    z1 = Subtract(Subtract(z1, z0), z2);
    byte[] resultArray = Add(z0, Add(Shift(z1, half), Shift(z2, 2*half)));
    return Normalize(resultArray);
}

private static void Split(byte[] x, int half, out byte[] low, out byte[] high) {
    high = new byte[Math.Max(1, x.Length - half)];
    if (x.Length > half) Array.Copy(x, half, high, 0, high.Length);
    Array.Resize(ref x, Math.Min(half, x.Length));
    low = x;
}

private static byte[] Add(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    int n = a.Length;
    int m = b.Length;
    int length = Math.Max(n, m);
    byte[] result = new byte[length + 1];
    byte carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { // Wrong direction
        byte sum = (byte) ((i < n ? a[i] : 0) + (i < m ? b[i] : 0) + carry);
        result[i] = (byte) (sum % 10);
        carry = (byte) (sum / 10);
    }
    result[length] = carry;
    return Normalize(result);
}

private static byte[] Subtract(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    int n = a.Length;
    int m = b.Length;
    byte[] result = new byte[n];
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int sub = a[i] - (i < m ? b[i] : 0) - carry;
        if (sub < 0) {
            sub += 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
        result[i] = (byte)sub;
    }
    return Normalize(result);
}

private static byte[] Mul(byte[] a, byte b) {
    byte[] result = new byte[a.Length + 1];
    byte carry = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
        byte product = (byte)(a[i] * b + carry);
        result[i] = (byte)(product % 10);
        carry = (byte)(product / 10);
    }
    result[a.Length] = carry;
    return Normalize(result);
}

private static byte[] Shift(byte[] a, int shift) {
    byte[] result = new byte[a.Length + shift];
    Array.Copy(a, 0, result, shift, a.Length);
    return result;
}

private static byte[] Normalize(byte[] a) {
    int n = a.Length - 1;
    if (a[n] > 0) return a; // No change needed
    while (n > 0 && a[n] == 0) {
        n--;
    }
    Array.Resize(ref a, n + 1);
    return a;
}
```

Note that it would have been more natural to use `List` instead of fixed sized arrays. This may be something you want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

The result is *not* just an "overlapping copy" of your `z0`, `z1`, and `z2` - have a look at the lengths, and revisit what description of Karatsuba multiplication you use.

`Add()` `z1` to the more significant quarters of the concatenation of `z0` and `z2`.

Your example:

```
X = Y = 2185  
expect = 04774225  
z1 = 11236  
     -7225  
      -441  
   =  3570  
z0 = 441  
z2 =    7225  
sum= 4774225
```

Comment: so How can i edit thhe code to solve this ?